# How to minimize web server re-direct traffic?

Tags: apache, http, redirect, webserver

When a user comes to my site (**example.com**) from a desktop browser, they will see the content as normal.

If a user comes to my site (example.com) from a mobile device, I want to redirect them to **m.example.com**

*Question: How do I minimize the round-trip network traffic to accomplish this?*

Reason being, this is what happens as of today (2 round trips)

```
   USER (BROWSER)                  |                     WEB-SERVER
-------------------------------------------------------------------
[1] request content from example.com   ========================>
   <================   tell browser to redirect to m.example.com [2]
[3] request content from m.example.com   =========================>
   <===================----------==   send m.example.com content [4]
```

Note that this is a wasted round trip (#3 & #4).

Is is possible to just send the m.example.com content in #2, while at the same time telling the browser this is coming from m.example.com? (1 roundtrip)

```
   USER (BROWSER)          |            WEB-SERVER
--------------------------------------------------
[1] request content from example.com =============>
<======== send content from m.example.com (& tell browser this is m.example.com) [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 kinds of redirects, client-side & server-side. Check if your language supports server-side redirect. It shall eliminate 1 step at least, if not 2.

Comment: Can I do this with the web server itself (e.g. Apache, NGINX)? Instead of the server side programming language?

Comment: Sorry, 'am not really sure about that.